Optimization Issue with Parameters in Squared Error Minimization
I am working on optimizing parameters in a model where the goal is to reduce the squared error of a predicted vector compared to a given vector. I am using scipy.optimize.minimize for this purpose. I have four parameters to optimize: w_y, w_p, w_r, and u_id. It seems that the parameters related to angles (w_y, w_p, w_r) are not changing during optimization; they remain at their initial values. I am not sure why this is happening. Could someone help me identify what might be going wrong?
Here is a simplified version of my code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Define the cosine function
def func(w, params):
    a, b, c, d = params
    radian = (w * np.pi) / 180
    return a * np.cos(b * radian + c) + d

# Define the objective function to minimize
def objective(params, W, x, params_y, params_p, params_r):
    w_y, w_p, w_r = params[:3]
    u_id = params[3:]

    # Compute the vectors f^y, f^p, f^r using parameter matrices
    f_y = np.array([func(w_y, p) for p in params_y])
    f_p = np.array([func(w_p, p) for p in params_p])
    f_r = np.array([func(w_r, p) for p in params_r])

    # Compute x^hat
    x_hat = np.einsum('ijklm,i,j,k,l->m', W, u_id, f_y, f_p, f_r)

    # Compute the L2 norm (squared error)
    return np.sum((x - x_hat) ** 2)

def optimize_params(W, x, u_id_shape, params_y, params_p, params_r):
    # Initial guesses for w^y, w^p, w^r and u_id (angles set to 0, u_id set to zeros)
    initial_guess = np.zeros(3 + u_id_shape)  # 3 for w^y, w^p, w^r and u_id_shape for u_id

    # Perform the optimization
    result = minimize(objective, initial_guess, args=(W, x, params_y, params_p, params_r), method='L-BFGS-B')

    # Extract the optimized parameters
    optimized_w_y, optimized_w_p, optimized_w_r = result.x[:3]
    optimized_u_id = result.x[3:]

    # Output the results
    print("Optimized angles:")
    print("w^y:", optimized_w_y)
    print("w^p:", optimized_w_p)
    print("w^r:", optimized_w_r)

    # Calculate the error after optimization
    error_after_optimization = objective(result.x, W, x, params_y, params_p, params_r)
    print(f"Error after optimization: {error_after_optimization}")

    print("\nOptimized u_id vector:")
    print(optimized_u_id)

    return optimized_w_y, optimized_w_p, optimized_w_r, optimized_u_id

# Example usage
W = np.array([...])  # Define your tensor W here
x = np.array([...])  # Define your target vector x here
u_id_shape = ...  # Define the shape of u_id
params_y = np.array([...])  # Parameter matrix for yaw
params_p = np.array([...])  # Parameter matrix for pitch
params_r = np.array([...])  # Parameter matrix for roll

optimize_params(W, x, u_id_shape, params_y, params_p, params_r)

After running the optimization, the angle parameters w_y, w_p, and w_r remain at their initial values, which suggests that they are not being optimized correctly. I have verified that the rest of the code works and correctly updates u_id.
My questions:

Are there any mistakes in how I am defining the objective function or initializing the parameters?
Could there be an issue with the optimization method or parameter bounds?
How can I debug this issue to ensure the angles are being optimized?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Difficult to say without having a runnable piece of code. What happens if you print the values of your angles in your objective function? Maybe L-BFGS-B is taking too small steps. Try and modify the “eps” parameter in the options keyword you can pass to minimize(), maybe use 1e-6 or something similar.
